# Vuex в Nuxt.js копирование

Tags: javascript, vue.js, spa, vuex

Получается так что Vuex в Nuxt общий для всех подключенных пользователей. Как сделать так что бы каждому пользователю отдавалась копия, а не оригинальный экземпляр.